# Openshift authenticity of host cant be established, when creating app

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I try to create an app in Openshift but alwas get the following error during the process:

**Cloning into 'firstapp'...

The authenticity of host 'firstapp-********.rhcloud.com (*********)' can't b
e established.

RSA key fingerprint is ******************************************.**

I used `rhc setup` to create the ssh keys and they were succesfully transfered into my Openshift account. Did I miss something or did something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I create an app, this is the relevant snippet I get:

```
Cloning into 'tsunade23'...  
The authenticity of host 'tsunade23-*.rhcloud.com (a.b.c.d)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is *:*:::::*:*.
No matching host key fingerprint found in DNS.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

So, are you seeing the last 2 lines from my snippet when you create the app? If yes, just type 'yes' and you should be good to go.

Let me know if this isn't the case.